# Are 3D kernels in convolutions summed over their channels?

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, convolution, convolutional-neural-network

Say for example that I have a 28x28x1 grey scale image and I will perform two consecutive convolutions. The first convolution has 2 3x3x1 filters and the second has 3 3x3x2 filters. Each convolution is done without padding and with a stride of 1. According to what i have read online the output after both convolutions would in this case be 24x24x3, if i've understood it correctly. The only way i understand that we could get this shape is by summing the 3D kernels over their channels, like we do when convolving over a RGB image. I've demonstrated what i mean in the image below:
[image]

It is the step were we go from 3 24x24x2 images to 3 24x24x1 images that i'm wondering about. Is this how convolutions are performed, by summing over the channels (2 channels in this case)? If not, how do we get the output shape of 24x24x3?

Comment: Yes that's it, they are summed over. That's why we get only one feature map if we only use one kernel..